# Insert multiple rows using form and PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Hello guys i am stuck in PHP code to Insert multiple rows using form and PDO
Below my code please help me to fix it
I'll appreciate all comments and suggested solutions
and forgive my mistakes because I am new i PHP

HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname[]"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email[]"><br>
<hr>
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname[]"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email[]"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $firstname = input_checker($_POST["firstname"]);
        $lastname = input_checker($_POST["lastname"]);
        $email = input_checker($_POST["email"]);   

        foreach ($row as $rows) {
            // prepare sql and bind parameters
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memo (firstname, lastname, email) 
            VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $rows);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $rows);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $rows);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo "New records created successfully";
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

function input_checker($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent please, it's hard to read.

It can't work.
DONT FOREACH THE QUERY. You'll send one query with bad datas as many times as you have elements in $rows array

What you're doing here is sending nothing cause $rows don't exist.

So here are the steps.
Do

```
$rows = array($firstname, $lastname, $email);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memo(ID, firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname, :email)");
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
         $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}
$stmt -> execute();
```

OR you can try building the query this way :
DB_connect :

```
<?php
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "veterinaires";
    /* PDO EN FR OU EN ARABE C ISSI */
    $db_options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name};charset=utf8", $db_username, $db_password, $db_options);
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Query :

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO patients
                    (ID,
                    pet_name,
                    breed,
                    colour,
                    sex,
                    date_of_birth,
                    microchip_tatoo,
                    comment,
                    owner_ID)
                VALUES
                    (NULL,
                    :pet_name,
                    :breed,
                    :colour,
                    :sex,
                    :date_of_birth,
                    :microchip_tatoo,
                    :comment,
                    :owner_ID)";
        $query_params = array(':pet_name' => $pet_name,
                              ':breed' => $breed,
                             ':colour' => $colour,
                             ':sex' => $sex,
                             ':date_of_birth' => $date_of_birth,
                             ':microchip_tatoo' => $microchip_tatoo,
                             ':comment' => $comment,
                             ':owner_ID' => $_SESSION['ID']);
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            $check = true;
        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            $check = false;
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
?>
```

Comment: You know the `execute` in the loop or it will only execute the last bound value.